# Link to older links

Tags: posts, pages, links

Im trying to have 5 posts for page in my blog. This is what Ive used in index.php

```
<?php
    get_header();
    query_posts('posts_per_page=5');

    // The Loop
    if (have_posts()){

        while (have_posts()){

            //Iterate the cursor on the next post
            the_post();

            echo "<a class='more-link' href='";
            the_permalink();
            echo "'><h1>";
            the_title();
            echo "</h1></a>";

            echo "<div class='meta'>";
            the_date();
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            comments_number();
            echo "</div>";

            echo "<a class='more-link' href='";
            the_permalink();
            echo "'>";
            the_post_thumbnail();
            echo "</a>";

            the_excerpt();
            echo "<a class='more-link' href='";
            the_permalink();
            echo "'>Continue reading</a>";

            echo "<hr>";
        }
    }

    get_footer();
?>
```

I want to put a link at the bottom for "show older posts", but I dont know how should I alter the file to do this. Any idea, please? Thank you

Comment: Your loop ends at the file footer.php - can you paste that one too?

Comment: There no additional PHP code, just closing tags </body></htm>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok then... try this (hope i got your request right):

**REVISED**

```
<?php
    get_header();
    query_posts( array(
          'posts_per_page' => 5,
          'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 ),
     ));

    // The Loop
    if (have_posts()){

        while (have_posts()){

            //Iterate the cursor on the next post
            the_post();

            echo "<a class='more-link' href='";
            the_permalink();
            echo "'><h1>";
            the_title();
            echo "</h1></a>";

            echo "<div class='meta'>";
            the_date();
            echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            comments_number();
            echo "</div>";

            echo "<a class='more-link' href='";
            the_permalink();
            echo "'>";
            the_post_thumbnail();
            echo "</a>";

            the_excerpt();
            echo "<a class='more-link' href='";
            the_permalink();
            echo "'>Continue reading</a>";

            echo "<hr>";
        }
    }
    ?>
    <div class="navigation">
      <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?></div>
      <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('More &raquo;') ?></div>
    </div>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

.

Hope this helps,
Cheers, Sagive.

Comment: Thats not what I mean. What I want is a link to the list of the NEXT 5 older posts. With that I will only see the 6th newest post.

Comment: Aplogies.. didnt see that query at the head of your loop, try it now..

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! I didnt know the "paged" option. Million thanks ;)

Comment: My pleasure mate ;)